# What is the syntax to write or update records in CQDB for Rational ClearQuest 7?

Tags: api, syntax, updates, fwrite, clearquest

What is the syntax in Rational CQ 7 API to write or update records into CQDB from an external table like excel using VBA.I want to create a macro in excel where using VBA and the syntax to write/update records into CQDB.So is there any specific syntax for that?
Thanks